# Expressing weird equation in terms of big theta

Tags: linear-algebra, homogeneous-equation

one of the questions on my homework is expressing below formula in terms of big Theta.

$f(n)=4f(n-1)+4f(n-2)$

clearly it looks linear homogeneous but when I try to start the solution by
$x^2 - 4x - 4=0$, there is no factors.

we have another options to solve it either by expansion which is very costly and not logical or using change of variable which I couldn't do.

anyone has an idea your help is very appreciated.

Comment: the equation should be $x^2-4x-4=0$.

Comment: $x^2 = 4x + 4$ that is to say $x^2 - 4x-4 =0$ could be better, I think.

Comment: it's actually as you said, but there is no direct factors for this formula to make the solution acceptable. it will take us to fractions.

Comment: not fractions. irrationals. So what ? and what is "big theta" ?